# shooting intervals in cocos2d without CACurrentMediaTime()

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have a ship and I want to make it to shoot every 1 sec. So here's what I did,

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) float lastDamageTime;
```

and in the update method,

```
if (CACurrentMediaTime - self.lastDamageTime > 1)
{
    self.lastDamageTime = CACurrentMediaTime;
    [self shoot];
}
```

But the problem is, say I pause the game right after the ship shoot a bullet, and then 1 sec later, I resume the game, the if statement pass the check, and the ship will shoot another bullet immediately. And that's not what I want.

So, what can I do to make sure the ship fire bullets each sec weather I pause the game or not? Should I use CCTimer instead?

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try and schedule your shoots as a `CCRepeatForever` action, so that cocos2d deals with pause for you. It'd look something like this (assuming you're inside a custom `ShipSprite`).-

```
CCDelayTime *delay = [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:1.0];
CCCallFunc *funcShoot = [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(shoot)];
CCRepeatForever *repeat = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCSequence actionOne:delay two:funcShoot]];
[self runAction:repeat];
```

Comment: yeah, but if the ship detect an enemy, it will shoot in 1 sec instead of immediately shooting a bullet. Sorry I didn't state this in my main question. I wonder what would other developer do in this situation. I wonder using a cctimer would be better?

Comment: well, you could reverse the order of the sequence, calling shoot before the delay

Answer (score 0):

Instead of CCRepeatForever you can try something like this

```
[self schedule:@selector(shoot) interval:1];
```

In your pause code unschedule the shooting

```
[self unschedule:@selector(shoot)];
```

In your code where it detects an enemy call

```
[self unschedule:@selector(shoot)];
[self performSelector:@selector(shoot)];
[self schedule:@selector(shoot) interval:1];
```

And it will shoot immediately, however it will only shoot once and then restart at 1 second intervals etc... so if you need to change that you can just adjust the timings